# Best regression model for ratios of a zero-inflated Poisson with a zero-truncated Poisson random variables?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, ratio, beta-regression

I am working with data in which my dependent variables underlying probability distribution is a ratio of correlated ZTP-ish (ZTP = Zero-Truncated Poisson) random variables $Y = \frac{M}{C}$ with $C \sim ZTP(\lambda)$ and $M |(C=n) \sim B(n,p)$ so we have: $M \sim \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda p}}{1 - e^{-\lambda}}\text{ZTP}(\lambda p) \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{N}^*}  + \frac{e^{-\lambda p} - e^{-\lambda}}{1 - e^{-\lambda}} \delta_0$.  (At least that's the result I obtained) Thus, $M$ follows a Zero-Inflated Poisson distribution.

I know that the variance of my data is smaller when it gets closer to the borders of the $[0,1]$ interval, so I have to take heteroskedasticity into account.

Since $Y$'s support is  $[0,1]$ I thought about using a beta regression with a logit link function after applying an adequate transformation to stay inside $(0,1)$ and thus be defined. Moreover [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153941) in a similar situation they advise to use a beta distribution to approximate a ratio of Poisson distributions (By the way if anybody has any more reference on this please let me know, the only approximations of Poisson ratios I've found on the internet were made with a ratio of Normal distributions)

I don't really know much about the subject and I was wondering if there were a more natural regression model for my situation.

Comment: Are there two different processes?  Can you fit two models?  This sounds like a hurdle model in reverse.

Comment: There are three processes $M$, $C$ and $\frac{M}{C}$. I could fit two models but I want to find $\beta$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{M}{C}] = \beta X + \epsilon$ would it be possible with two models? Gonna look more deeply in the direction of hurdle models thank you!

Comment: A hurdle model is where there's one process that influences whether something happens at all, & if it does, a second process for how often.  It's for zero-inflated count data.  The models are logistic -> Poisson.  Your situation is the reverse.  I don't think a hurdle model will help you.  Taking $C$ as a given, $\mathbb{E}[\frac{M}{C}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$ is just logistic regression.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the idea behind your model. When you write $M |C=n \sim B(n,p)$, how does the value of $C$ determine either the number of trials or the probability of success for the process that produces $M$?

Comment: $C$ is the number of individuals ($>1$) who's given an exam with probability $p$ of passing, and $M$ is the number of these individuals who passes the test. $C$ follows a zero-truncated Poisson distribution and when the value of $C$ is given, $M$ follows a Bernoulli distribution with number of trials $C$ and probability of success $p$.

Comment: So you want to estimate the probability $p=M/C$? Do you expect the covariates $X$ to affect both $C$ and $p$? Please add that information, and information from your prior comments, into the question by editing it, as comments are very easy to overlook.